# How can I tell if a value is 0 in a 2D array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays

New to coding, I am creating a pos for a shop that must contain stock levels for every item and when an item is out of stock it is supposed to not allow the user to choose that item. It reads the stock level from a 2d array. I have it so when an item in an array is 0 it tells the user but it doesn't specify which item. How can I find if that specific item is out of stock.

```
private void AddCartButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ShirtIndex = 0, SizeIndex = 0;
    decimal ShirtCost = 0m;

    if (ShirtListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if (SizeListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            if (ShirtStock[ShirtIndex, SizeIndex] != 0) 
            {
                ShirtIndex = ShirtListBox.SelectedIndex;
                SizeIndex = SizeListBox.SelectedIndex;
                Shirt = ShirtsArray[ShirtIndex];
                ShirtCost = ShirtPrice[ShirtIndex];
                SizeOfItem = Sizes[SizeIndex];
                CartListBox.Items.Add(Shirt + " - " + SizeOfItem + " = " + ShirtCost);
                PriceListBox.Items.Add(ShirtCost);
                TotalCost = TotalCost + ShirtCost;
                TotalTextBox.Text = TotalCost.ToString();

                //Taking away stock 
                ShirtStock[ShirtIndex, SizeIndex] = ShirtStock[ShirtIndex, SizeIndex] - 1;
                // Write to stock File Method
                WritingToStock();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO Stock");
            }
```

Comment: Is "pos" a "Point of Sale system"?  I'm guessing this is homework, and that you are currently working with/studying arrays.  If that is not the case, please mention it - in real life, arrays are not a great solution for this problem

Comment: It looks like you might want to set `int ShirtIndex = ShirtListBox.SelectedIndex, SizeIndex = SizeListBox.SelectedIndex;` instead of `int ShirtIndex = 0, SizeIndex = 0;` because otherwise you'll alway be checking the [0,0] item for stock.

Comment: Yes this is for an assignment where we must use arrays and @ekke YOU GENIUS I cannot believe i never realised that. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: By the way, if you rate this "homework question" on the scale of other homework questions that are posted on this site, yours is definitely in the top decile, perhaps even higher.  It's not the perfect Stackoverflow question, but it's definitely a good one - particularly, one coming from a student.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're indexing into the array correctly. The problem is your indexes are always 0, which is how you initialized them as local variables. I think you meant to use the indexes from the user input instead.

So instead of

```
if (ShirtStock[ShirtIndex, SizeIndex] != 0)
```

Try

```
if (ShirtStock[ShirtListBox.SelectedIndex, SizeListBox.SelectedIndex] != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I never realised that the code was only looking at [0,0] because I intialised it to do that. So instead of

```
int ShirtIndex = 0, SizeIndex = 0;
```

it is now

```
int ShirtIndex = ShirtListBox.SelectedIndex, SizeIndex = SizeListBox.SelectedIndex;
```

Thanks Ekke!